# checking for a duplcate value entered inside dropdown box with same class through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

There are 5 dropdowns having same class 'className'. I have to make sure that the values entered in the dropdowns are not duplicate.

now, I can access the dropdowns in jquery by class like this

```
$('.className').each(function(){
    //my Ques:: code to check if duplicate values are entered by the user 
    });
```

My ques is stated inside the comment as "my ques"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the selected value is the same on the others using [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val) and [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

### Filter:

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or
>   pass the function's test.

Code:

```
function inputsHaveDuplicateValues() {
    var hasDuplicates = false;
    $('.className').each(function () {
        var inputsWithSameValue = $(this).val();
        hasDuplicates = $('.className').not(this).filter(function () {
            return $(this).val() === inputsWithSameValue;
        }).length > 0;
        if (hasDuplicates) return false
    });
    return hasDuplicates;
}

$('button').click(function () {
    alert(inputsHaveDuplicateValues());
})
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/u3czyjt4/

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there are a number of ways to solve this. For example, you can store the values of each combo in an array, and in each iteration, check if it was already stored in the array previously.

```
var values = [];
$('.className').each(function(element, index){
    if (values.indexOf($(this).val()) >= 0) {
        //already exists
        return false; //break the loop 
    }
    values[index] = $(this).val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   var array = [];  // push all the values in array 
     $('.className').each(function(){       
        // check if the value is in array
        if( $.inArray($(this).val(),array) > 0)
           console.log('duplicate found ', $(this).val());
        else           
          array.push($(this).val()
        // if not insert into array
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the hashtable to check for duplicate entries. Check this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/v025hkjn/

```
var hashtable = {};
$(".className").each(function () {
if(hashtable[this.text]) {
    $(this).remove();
} else {
    hashtable[this.text] = this.value;
}
});
```

for html may be like below

```
<select>
   <option class='className' value="volvo">Volvo</option>
   <option class='className' value="saab">Saab</option>
   <option class='className' value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
   <option class='className' value="audi">Audi</option>
   <option class='className' value="volvo">Volvo</option>
   <option class='className' value="volvo">Volvo</option>
   <option class='className' value="volvo">Volvo</option>
</select>
```